# How can I remove random gook from a wall ...?

Tags: walls, paint, removal, caulk

... without damaging the wall.

I previously started renting a room and the walls are a bit of a mess.

I'm not a handy man but wanted to clean them up.

I can't say for certain what the material is but it looks like caulk or a paste of some kind.

[image]

Comment: Talk to the landlord...

Comment: Have you tried  random soap, water and rag ?